# using left join along with 'IS NULL'

Tags: mysql, left-join

I came across this query to get a row having max value. Can you explain how this works

```
SELECT s1.article, s1.dealer, s1.price, s2.article, s2.dealer, s2.price
FROM shop s1
LEFT JOIN shop s2 ON s1.price < s2.price
WHERE s2.article IS NULL;
```

Dump :

```
CREATE TABLE `shop` (
`article` int(4) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000',
`dealer` char(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`price` double(16,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
PRIMARY KEY (`article`,`dealer`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `shop` VALUES 
(0001,'A',3.45), (0001,'B',3.99), 
(0002,'A',10.99),(0003,'B',1.45),
(0003,'C',1.69),(0003,'D',1.25),
(0004,'D',19.95);
```

Comment: This query retrieves 6 fields from 2 tables (3 from each) synchronizing the results of both tables by the condition that the PRICE field on table 1 is less than that in table 2 and that the article in table 2 is null. There is no MAX value processing at all.

Comment: @RyanVincent I do not understand how the left join condition works along with the is null condition to give the desired result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query performs a self join based on the predicate:

```
s1.price < s2.price
```

So, each record of the table is joined to any record having a greater price.

The predicate of the `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE s2.article IS NULL
```

is `true` when *no such record exists*. Hence the query returns the record having the greatest price.

Comment: so basically , a check is done till there is no higher value ( which is when s2.article is null ).. is that correct?

Comment: @mercy If, for a specific record, `s2.article IS NULL=true`, this means that this record has no match using the predicate of the `ON` clause. Which means this record has no other record exceeding its `price` value.

Answer (score 0):

Why

```
WHERE s2.article IS NULL
```

is used, from the MySQL reference:

> The LEFT JOIN works on the basis that when s1.price is at its maximum value, there is no s2.price with a greater value and thus the corresponding s2.article value is NULL